Unexpected generated infinite loop where there is no side effect
When a program  built with gcc 8.4.3 and -O2, following loop was turned into an assembly code of infinite one
for(int i=0; i < PCU_MAX; i++) 
{
     auto loc = getApp()->Loc[i + 1 + PCU_LOCATION];
     if (loc.isUpdated() ) loc.setUpdated ( false );
}

Due to nature of symptom "it hanged there" I was looking in wrong places for a source of deadlock instead of peeking into a assembly. Finally, when I did try to print value of i in gdb, it appeared to be optimized out. The assembly of this loop:
8x782f29 <MainWindow:: updateInfo(int)+352> mov 8xc31899(%rip),%rsi
8x782f27 <MainWindow:: updateInfo(int)+359> mov $0x882700,%edi
8x782f2c <MainWindow:: updateInfo(int)+364> callq 0x42da40 <_2NK11QMetaObject4castEP7Q0bject@plt>
0x782f31 <MainWindow:: updateInfo(int)+369> jmp 0x782f20 <MainWindow:: updateInfo(int)+352>

Apparently, this contained tho major error, getApp()->Loc is an array, so it really should have been auto& loc=, loop doesn't have side effect. GCC optimized i and ended up with infinite loop, because the end condition disappeared. Why it would do so, is it a legitimate UB?
Apparently this had an error by one - last iteration went just right outside of array end. But it was a "safe area" occupied by same type and inspecting one element past array end isn't an UB... or is it now?
Argument 1: taking an address past end of array isn't an UB. Inspecting and changing it is.
Argument 2: isUpdated() and setUpdated()  don't have side-effects related to change of an element of Loc, even if they look like. But to call it is an UB, because it's a non-static function member. the fact, that this might be pointing at a correct object, is irrelevant?
Removing any of these two factors produces a correct loop. Removing if (loc.isUpdated() ) loc.setUpdated ( false ); and setting  auto& loc still produces an infinite loop. It looks like first gcc optimizes out i and then "It's an infinite loop without visible side effects, because I made it infinite, and it's an UB".

Inspecting one element beyond an array is UB. You might be getting confused with std::string where it would not be UB.

@wohlstad yes, I know, but this UB is one of Munchausen kind, it creates itself. Unless  compiler had considerd that it would remove last iteration and  the check.

The fact that Loc is an array has no bearing on whether loc is a reference or not. The only possible difference for the above code is that you avoid a copy constructor call if loc is a reference.

@john in case if SomeClass::operator[] does whatever, e.g. being a map, it does matter, author of this code had mistaken it for a container which was returning an std::reference_wrapper. Cargo cult programming is an evil widespread in that team.

"inspecting one element past array end isn't an UB... or is it..." It is UB.

curiously, version used by godbolt  of 8.4 doesn't do any of these things, it removes loop completely, but they have a later build than mainstream. Odd behaviour completely localized to 4.8.3 included with earlier debian.


"[...]inspecting one element past array end isn't an UB... or is it now?"

As far as I know, accessing an out-of-bounds element of an array (including one past the end) always has been Undefined Behaviour.
So whether or not it works if you add the missing reference cannot be taken for granted as long as the UB is not removed first.
